# compiling lambdaworks scrypt for android

Tags: android, android-ndk, scrypt

I developing an Android app which need to use scrypt library from lambaworks ( [this one](https://github.com/wg/scrypt)) which only contains the .so file only for one architecture and they write that you must compile the library yourself for all other platoform but I really don't know how to do this since I'm not C expert at all and I never used NDK. Can some of you explain me how can I compile the library to obtain .so files for all architectures?

many thanks